# Need Clarification on Bitwise Operators in Chris Rolliston XE2 Foundations Page 65

Tags: delphi, bitwise-operators

Me being a newbie trudging through Chris's book has a question.

On page 65 last paragraph mentions using proper set types as they provide strong typing.

Can someone explain what is meant by this as the example that follows looks like something I would typical do,  I am trying to use better practices.

Comment: Can you give more details? I'm guessing that Chris was comparing C style bitwise AND and OR operators on integer types (like window styles, or process creation flags from Win32) with Delphi sets. But it would be better if we did not have to guess. Do you know what strong typing is? Did you look it up with a websearch?

Comment: We don't have page 65 of Chris' book in front of us. It's great that  Chris is on here and can explain, but this is a terrible question in general.  How about asking about the actual syntax instead of a page reference?

Answer (score 9):

As I can't impinge my own copyright, the complete section:

*There are a few places in the Delphi RTL — and many, many places in the Windows API — where ‘bitmasks’ on an integer of some sort are used instead of proper set types. For example, the `System.SysUtils` unit declares a function, `FileGetAttr`, that returns the attributes of a file (read only, hidden, system, etc.) in the form of a single integer. To test for individual attributes, you must use so-called ‘bitwise’ operators, in particular `and`:*

```
uses
  System.SysUtils;

var
  Attr: Integer;
begin
  Attr := FileGetAttr('C:\Stuff\Some file.txt');
  if Attr and faReadOnly <> 0 then
    WriteLn('Read only');
  if Attr and faHidden <> 0 then
    WriteLn('Hidden');
  if Attr and faSysFile <> 0 then
    WriteLn('System');
end.
```

*For this to work, the `faXXX` constants are defined so that the first has a value of 1, the second a value of 2, the third a value of 4, the fourth of 8 and so on. To add a value to an existing manual ‘set’, use `or`, and to remove a value, use `and not`:*

```
procedure AddHiddenAttr(const AFileName: string);
begin
  FileSetAttr(AFileName, FileGetAttr(AFileName) or faHidden);
end;

procedure RemoveHiddenAttr(const AFileName: string);
begin
  FileSetAttr(AFileName, FileGetAttr(AFileName) and not faHidden);
end;
```

*In general, you should use proper set types where you can, since they provide strong typing and greater readability. Nonetheless, the following code demonstrates the fact that under the bonnet, ‘real’ sets and their manual, C-style equivalents boil down to the same thing:*

```
const
  mcFirst  = 1;
  mcSecond = 2;
  mcThird  = 4;
  mcFourth = 8;

type
  TMyEnum = (meFirst, meSecond, meThird, meFourth);
  TMySet = set of TMyEnum;

var
  UsingSet: TMySet;
  UsingConsts: LongWord;
begin
  //direct assignment
  UsingSet := [meSecond, meThird];
  UsingConsts := mcSecond or mcThird;
  WriteLn('Equal? ', Byte(UsingSet) = UsingConsts);
  //subtraction
  Exclude(UsingSet, meSecond);
  UsingConsts := UsingConsts and not mcSecond;
  WriteLn('Equal? ', Byte(UsingSet) = UsingConsts);
  //addition
  Include(UsingSet, meFourth);
  UsingConsts := UsingConsts or mcFourth;
  WriteLn('Equal? ', Byte(UsingSet) = UsingConsts);
  //membership test
  if meThird in UsingSet then WriteLn('meThird is in');
  if UsingConsts and mcThird <> 0 then WriteLn('mcThird is in');
end.
```

*Run the program, and you’ll find `TRUE` outputted in each case.*

So... having just gone through enumerations and set types, I'm now covering the weakly-typed equivalent. The implication of the bit at the end is that if you are used to defining simple bitmasks in the C fashion, there is no reason to avoid using proper set types in Delphi since they boil down to the same thing. As such, you aren't losing any efficiency as you gain strong typing - 'strong typing' itself in this context meaning you cannot accidentally assign or test for an element that is intended for a different sort of set.

Comment: See, I knew you'd come back! You might want to use the quote formatting rather than italics.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - I used quote formatting at first, but then changed to italics when the final 'and' in the first paragraph just ran into the preceeding text (the quote formatting uses a gray background like the code formatting).

Comment: I think it looks much better quoted. It's not hard to spot the code. And it better delineates the quote from your final explanatory paragraph, in my view.

Answer (score 1):

The code you reference is a comparison of using constants vs enumerated types and demonstrates that both methods work just fine.

```
const
  mcFirst = 1;
  ...
```

vs

```
type
  TMyEnum = (meFirst, ...
```

Chris is suggesting the use of enumerated types, rather than constants, to take advantage of strong typing .

Comment: Perhaps you can explain strong typing issues

Comment: Ahh, I got this some hours after I read it.  My understanding is an enumerated type could allow sweeping changes by making a single edit of the enumerated type.  Thanks, Tim C.